# How to remove audio permission for React-Native-Camera with RN CLI

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm developing an app for taking a profile image with the react-native-camera library.
That app does not have a recording feature. so it will not require audio permission. but that RNCamera asks for "record audio" permission. So how to remove that permission from my app.

Please help me, (Thanks in Advance).

I do not want to appear dialog box asking for audio recording rights as shown in Figure 1
[image]

**Here is my code:**

````
<RNCamera
        ref={cameraRef}
        type={cameraType}
        ratio={'4:3'}
        style={styles.preview}
        captureAudio={false}
        androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
          title: 'Permission to use camera',
          message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
          buttonPositive: 'Ok',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        }}>
        <Box
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            paddingBottom: 50,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-around',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.clsButton}
            onPress={() => {
              close();
            }}>
            <Image source={assets.CloseIcon} style={styles.clsButtonIcon} />
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.captureButton}
            onPress={captureHandle}>
            <Image source={assets.Camera} />
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.switchButton}
            onPress={handleCameraSwitch}>
            <Image style={styles.switchIcon} source={assets.SwapCameraIcon} />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </Box>
      </RNCamera> ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass: `captureAudio={false}` to the RNCamera component.

```
<RNCamera
          ref={ref => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
          captureAudio={false}
          onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
            console.warn(barcodes[0].data);
            if (!Utils.isNull(barcodes[0].data) & this.isCan) {
              this.runAction(barcodes[0].data)
            }
          }}
/>
```